# Angular/Typescript - how to get a new list from objects depending on property?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have two lists of objects:

```
groups = [
  { 
    id: 1,
    ...
  },
  { 
    id: 2,
    ...
  },
  { 
    id: 3,
    ...
  }
]

devices = [
  { 
    id: 1,
    group_id: 1,
    ...
  },
  { 
    id: 2,
    group_id: 1,
    ...
  },
  { 
    id: 3,
    group_id: 2,
    ...
  }
]
```

Now I want to have a new list with grouped devices ids depending of a group_id.

```
groupedDevices = [
  {
    id: [1,2] //group 1
  },
  {
    id:[3] //group 2
  }
]
```

Or maybe in another form but it should be a new list. I tried looping after objects in both lists but no results, I can't get it

Answer (score 1):

1. First group devices by group id:

   ```
   const devicesByGroupId = new Map<number, number[]>();
   for (const device of devices) {
     const devices = devicesByGroupId.get(device.group_id);
     if (!devices) {
       devicesByGroupId.set(device.group_id, [device.id]);
     } else {
       devices.push(device.id);
     }
   }
   ```
2. Then, assign devices to the groups and filter out empty ones:

   ```
   let groupedDevices = groups.map(group => {
     return {
       id: devicesByGroupId.get(group.id) || []
     };
   })
   .filter(group => group.id.length > 0);
   ```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let devices = [
      { 
        id: 1,
        group_id: 1
      },
      { 
        id: 2,
        group_id: 1
      },
      { 
        id: 3,
        group_id: 2
      }
    ]
    let groupDevices=_.groupBy(devices,function(x){          return x.group_id
    });
    
    let newObj=[];
    _.forEach(groupDevices,function(x){
    newObj.push({id:_.map(x,'id')});
    });
    console.log(newObj);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```